# APPIUM ERR = org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Cud not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address

Tags: java, appium

1) installed & ran appium-doctor and everything is installed fine on mac 10.9.5
2) have added selenium(2.45.0) & junit jar files also in eclipse
3) started appium(appium &) and ran but it is giving me error.
4) I tried different ports http://127.0.0.1 port 4723 and http://0.0.0.0 port 4444
but still getting errors.

Please help

***Here's error***

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: test.java.com.saucelabs.appium.AppiumIOSTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.017 sec <<< FAILURE!
testScriptGoesHere(test.java.com.saucelabs.appium.AppiumIOSTest)  Time elapsed: 0.925 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'N/A', ip: 'N/A', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.5', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
    at test.java.com.saucelabs.appium.AppiumIOSTest.setUp(AppiumIOSTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: W803487DAGU: W803487DAGU: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: W803487DAGU: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
    ... 53 more

testScriptGoesHere(test.java.com.saucelabs.appium.AppiumIOSTest)  Time elapsed: 0.927 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.java.com.saucelabs.appium.AppiumIOSTest.tearDown(AppiumIOSTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

==========
Here's Eclipse Code:-

```
package test.java.com.saucelabs.appium;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.junit.*;
import java.awt.List;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;


public class AppiumIOSTest {  
private WebDriver driver;  

private List values;  

private static final int MINIMUM = 0;  
private static final int MAXIMUM = 10;  

@Before  
public void setUp() throws Exception {  

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "ios");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","iPhone");
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "a0a3443aaaaadddddcccc");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "com.abc.mobile");

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities );
    //driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:1111/wd/hub"),capabilities);

    //values = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
}  

@After  
public void tearDown() throws Exception {  
   driver.quit();  
}  


@Test  
public void testScriptGoesHere() throws Exception {  

    System.out.println("Test Output From Within the test");
    System.out.println("Here goes your test script");

}
```

}

POM.xml is fine too.

Please help in resolving this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your stack-trace is claiming it can't connect to the remote server.  So, either you're using the wrong address, you're having network problems (like a proxy server), or you don't have an Appium server running.

### Network Problems

This probably isn't the case.  You're trying to contact an Appium server on the same machine as your tests, is that correct?  Have you tried disabling any firewalls or VPN you have running?

### Address of Server

By default, Appium runs on port 4723.  In your code you're trying to contact a server at '0.0.0.0:4444':

`driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub")`

That's not a valid address, so your test code can't connect to an Appium server running there.  You said you tried `127.0.0.1:4723`, but in your code example you've got a commented out line using `localhost:1111`;  Is it possible you used the wrong port for your local Appium connection by mistake?

### Is Appium Running

Can you start Appium in a terminal window without the `&`, so that Appium runs in that terminal window?  What output do you get when you run Appium, and what happens when you try to connect?

If Appium starts successfully, what happens when you do `telnet localhost 4723` in a different terminal window?